# Modify a JSON array with inputs from a shell array in only a single pass

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

Is it possible to filter an entire array of items in JQ in only one pass? Compare the following code, which runs `jq` over and over:

```
{
      "foofoo": {
        "barbar": [
          {
            "foo": "aaaa",
            "bar": 0000
          },
          {
            "foo": "bbbb",
            "bar": 1111
          },
          {
            "foo": "cccc",
            "bar": 2222
          }
          ]
      }
}
```

bash array:

```
array=("1111" "2222")
```

my code is working but not very efficient and uses a lot of resources considering the array size in reality:

```
for k in "${array[@]}"; do 
    jq  --argjson k "$k"  '.foofoo.barbar |= map(select(.bar != $k))' json.json | sponge json.json 
done
```

It keeps looping through the array, removing the unneeded entries and storing same file again by using sponge.

any ideas how to achieve a similar behavior with a lighter code?

Desired output:

```
{
  "foofoo": {
    "barbar": [
      {
        "foo": "aaaa",
        "bar": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: added desired output to question

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes I mean without a shell loop

Comment: still, you won't get `0000` as output, it will be collapsed to `"bar": 0`

Comment: yes it is an integer so `0` or `0000` will not affect the functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve the performance significantly use the following `jq` approach (without any *shell* loops):

```
arr=("1111" "2222")
jq '($p | split(" ") | map(tonumber)) as $exclude 
    | .foofoo.barbar 
      |= map(select(.bar as $b 
                    | any($exclude[]; . == $b) | not))' \
    --arg p "${arr[*]}" file.json | sponge file.json
```

The output:

```
{
  "foofoo": {
    "barbar": [
      {
        "foo": "aaaa",
        "bar": 0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check the last edit as .bar value is unquoted in the JSON file

Comment: @ma7555 That's not valid JSON; strings **must** be in quotes. Try it yourself: `jq . <<<'{"bar": aaaa}'` fails with an "invalid numeric literal" error. So does `python -m json.tool <<<'{"bar": aaaa}'`, to show you that that's not just a jq limitation.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it is actually an integer, I resembled it as a string just as an example. I might have caused a confusion with this

Comment: [mcve] guidelines require that an example be "verifiable" -- it must not cause errors unrelated to the actual question.

Comment: @ma7555, you need to post the actual input avoiding invalid samples

Comment: Hmm. I'd be tempted to use `fromjson` on each `split()` result (and maybe switch from spaces to newlines as the separators); that'll parse numeric literals as literals, but also let string literals be used by including literal quotes.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest my apology I have edited the question to be verifiable

Comment: @ma7555, see my update and keep in mind that JSON notation will treat `0000` as single `0`

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes expected, Thanks for taking the time to edit your answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm positive there are better ways to do this: I really just throw stuff at jq until something sticks to the wall ...

```
# 1. in the shell, construct a JSON object string from the array => {"bbbb":1,"cccc":1}
printf -v jsonobj '{%s}' "$(printf '"%q":1\n' "${array[@]}" | paste -sd,)"

# 2. use that to test for non-membership in the jq select function
jq --argjson o "$jsonobj" '.foofoo.barbar |= map(select((.bar|in($o)) == false))' json.json
```

outputs

```
{
  "foofoo": {
    "barbar": [
      {
        "foo": "0000",
        "bar": "aaaa"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You don't actually show your desired output, so I assume this is what you want.

Comment: One might also use `map(select($o[.bar]!=1))` :)

Answer (score 0):

Constructing a dictionary object opens the door to an efficient solution.  If your jq has `INDEX/2`, you could use the following invocation:

```
jq --arg p "${arr[*]}" '
  INDEX($p | split(" ")[]; .) as $dict
  | .foofoo.barbar 
      |= map(select($dict[.bar|tostring] | not))'
```

If your jq does not have `INDEX/2`, then now would be an excellent time to upgrade; otherwise, you could snarf its def by googling:
`jq "def INDEX"`